# MYSQL configuration for multiple and bulk records insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am inserting more then 1 million records  and my each insert query inserts 15000 records  by single query at a time  it is taking 1 min to inserting 1 million records

like this :-

```
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')........................
```

but when i execute 2 query at a time mysql goes slow and it is taking 25-30 min.

what mysql configuration i should use for solve this problem

Comment: Do all the queries insert into the same table?

Comment: no tables are different .

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you insert 15000 records like this:

```
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
insert into records (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

.....
```

If so try using INSERT ALL

```
INSERT ALL INTO records (data) values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')

...........
```

It may take some work but if you group all of the inserts that go to the same table  so you can use INSERT ALL you can reduce the number of statements the server needs to parse, which is very expensive.

Comment: My queries are like this                                                                 1st insert into table1 (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')........................                                                                                                            2nd insert into table2 (data) values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d')........................           and tables are not same

Comment: So you have 15000 different tables to insert into?

Comment: no tables are only 2  . i am inserting data via 2 scripts  each scripts insert records into 1 table so 2 scripts inserting data into 2 different tables

Comment: Then I stand by my suggestion, parsing a statement is very expensive and reducing those 15000 statements per script into 1 per script should speed up the process quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *transactions*. This will improve but not necessarily fix your issue.

In PHP:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->beginTransaction();

foreach ($somethings as $something) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO records VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->execute([$something]); // PHP 5.5 will like this
    $stmt->execute(Array($something)); // PHP 5.4 or under.   
}

$pdo->commit();
```

But really for such large data entries you should consider just generating queries which do send 15000 values at once...

Comment: Since all of the inserts have the same statement structure you can pull out the $pdo->prepare and reuse it in the loop. And yes something like INSERT ALL would work wonders here.

Comment: i want to know my.cnf configuration

Comment: It can't be done using a configuration change as the way you are using sql is fundamentally wrong.